# Chef ERB template variable in a .each loop

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb

In a cookbook, I have a template resource:

```
clustered_machines = Array.new
nodes.each do |node|
  clustered_machines << node['hostname']
end

zookeeper_data_dir=node["lc_kafka"]["zookeeper_datadir"]
zookeeper_client_port=node["lc_kafka"]["zookeeper_client_port"]
zookeeper_client_Port_Address=node['hostname']
delete_topic=node["lc_kafka"]["delete_topic"]
brokerID=node["brokerID"]
logdir="#{kafka_home}/logs"
template "server.properties" do
  path "/#{kafka_home}/config/server.properties"
  source "server.properties.erb"
  owner "kafka"
  group "kafka"
  mode "0644"
  variables(
      :brokerID => brokerID,
      :logdir => logdir,
      :zookeeper_machines => clustered_machines,
      :zookeeper_client_port => zookeeper_client_port,
      :delete_topic_bool => delete_topic
  )
end
```

In the erb file I have the following:

```
log.retention.ms=-1
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
<%
zookeeper_connection_string = ""
@zookeeper_machines.each do |name|
  zookeeper_connection_string = zookeeper_connection_string + "#{name}"
end
zookeeper_connection_string = zookeeper_connection_string.chomp(", ")
%>
zookeeper.connect=<%= @zookeeper_connection_string %>
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

The end result file on disk should have this zookeeper_connection_string:

```
zookeeper.connect=kafka01:2181,kafka02:2181,kafka03:2181
```

This should come from the loop:

```
<%
zookeeper_connection_string = ""
@zookeeper_machines.each do |name|
  zookeeper_connection_string = zookeeper_connection_string + "#{name}":<%= @zookeeper_client_port %>
end
zookeeper_connection_string = zookeeper_connection_string.chomp(", ")
%>
zookeeper.connect=<%= @zookeeper_connection_string %>
```

But this variable that is coming from the template resource definition is trowing an exception because that variable in that loop, does not exists:

```
<%= @zookeeper_client_port %>
```

That variable can be define as such only outside of the loop.

My question is... is there any way to use that variable in the loop?
Thank you.
Gabriel

Later edit:

I've modified this part:

```
 nodes.each do |node|
   clustered_machines << "#{node['hostname']}:#{zookeeper_client_port}"
 end
```

And now I have the string ready to be inserted:

```
  [2019-11-01T20:46:00+02:00] WARN: clustered_machines are: ["kafka03:2181", "kafka02:2181", "kafka01:2181"]
```

I still don't know how to create the

```
zookeeper.connect=<%= @zookeeper_connection_string %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
<%
zookeeper_connection_string = ""
@zookeeper_machines.each do |name|
  zookeeper_connection_string = zookeeper_connection_string + "#{name},"
end
zookeeper_connection_string = zookeeper_connection_string.chomp(",")
%>
zookeeper.connect=<%= zookeeper_connection_string %>
```

The end result is:

```
zookeeper.connect=kafka01:2181,kafka02:2181,kafka03:2181
```

Comment: This looks like all you really need is `zookeeper_connection_string = @zookeeper_machines.join(',')` followed by `zookeeper.connect=<%= zookeeper_connection_string`